# How to connect Kafka with Windows Service Account using Confluent Kafka .Net Client

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I'm writing a Kafka Consumer using Confluent Kafka .net Client Library for an in-house application. Our Kafka Team has granted access via a windows service account and password.

Once I install the kafka Consumer application as a windows service and set the Log On Account with the password I'm able to consume data.

I would like to know, whether there are any configurations/options to set in ConsumerConfig to set service account and password in debug mode (without installing as a service). I'm debugging the consumer and related functionality in Visual Studio.

I would like to simulate same behavior while debugging the application.